# pivot_wider for Datasets

Tags: dataset

I'd like to transform this dataset:

```
Dataset[{
  <|"Name" -> "Steven","Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 115|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 230|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 70|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 300|>
}]
```

into this dataset:

```
Dataset[{
  <|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, "Score_2017" -> 115, "Score_2018" -> 230|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Score_2017" -> 70, "Score_2018" -> 300|>
}]
```

In R's [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) this operation is called [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html).

Any pointers?

I know that it requires a `GroupBy["Name"]`

Comment: Here is a related Community discussion: ["The main function I miss in Mathematica after reading a Python Pandas Book"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2002576)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the simplest way I could think off:

```
ds = Dataset[{
  <|"Name" -> "Steven","Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 115|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 230|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 70|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 300|>
}];
ds[
  GroupBy[#Name &],
  ResourceFunction["MergeByKey"][{{"Name", "Born"} -> First}]
][
  Values,
  Append[KeyDrop[#, {"Year", "Score"}],
    AssociationThread["Score_" <> ToString[#]& /@ #Year, #Score]
  ]&
]
```

[image]

If different people have different years, you might want to use `KeyUnion` to make the dataset square again. Documentation for `MergeByKey` is [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MergeByKey)

Comment: Thanks for writing and submitting to WFR `MergeByKey` !

Comment: Great! That works. I also found a solution with `Merge`, as I post below just for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the package ["DataReshape.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/DataReshape.m) as shown below. (It is in my ToDo list to submit the corresponding functions to Wolfram Function Repository very soon.)

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/DataReshape.m"]
```

Here is the original dataset:

```
dsData = Dataset[{<|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, 
     "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 115|>, <|"Name" -> "Steven", 
     "Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 230|>, <|
     "Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2017, 
     "Score" -> 70|>, <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Born" -> 1981, 
     "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 300|>}];
dsData
```

[image]

Let us convert it to a “proper” long form with ID variables all except “Score”:

```
dsLong = ToLongForm[dsData, {"Name", "Born", "Year"}, Automatic]
```

[image]

Here we change the values of the column “Variable” to have the values of the column “Year” as suffixes:

```
dsLong2 = 
 dsLong[All, 
  Join[KeyTake[#, {"Name", "Born", "Value"}], <|
     "Variable" -> 
      StringRiffle[{#Variable, ToString[#Year]}, "_"]|>] &]
```

[image]

Here we convert to wide form with ID variables “Name” and “Born”:

```
ToWideForm[dsLong2, {"Name", "Born"}, "Variable", "Value"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Such a package looks exactly what we would need for Dataset. R's tidy verse is very powerful to mangle data, and there is every reason to believe that a similar package for Wolfram Language would be equally powerful.

Comment: @Stephan Welcome! As for your comment "R's tidyverse is very powerful to mangle data [...]" -- sure, R-tydiverse is good with ***tabular data and collections of tabular data***. General data wrangling in R is still hard (with or without RStudio's packages.)

Answer (score 5):

Both Sjoerd's and Anton's answers work nicely. Upon Sjoerd's solution using `MergeByKey` from the Wolfram Function Repository, I just wanted to post here for completeness that one can find almost the same solution with `Merge` from the Wolfram Language:

```
ds = Dataset[{
  <|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 115|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Steven", "Born" -> 1980, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 230|>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe",    "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2017, "Score" -> 70 |>,
  <|"Name" -> "Joe",    "Born" -> 1981, "Year" -> 2018, "Score" -> 300|>
}];
ds[GroupBy["Name"], Merge[#, Identity] &][Values,
  Append[Map[First, KeyDrop[#, {"Year", "Score"}]], 
    AssociationThread["Score_" <> ToString[#] & /@ #Year, #Score]] &]
```